# How can I delete the second word of every line of top(1) output?

Tags: unix, sed

I have a formatted list of processes (top output) and I'd like to remove unnecessary information. How can I remove for example the second word+whitespace of each line.

Example:

```
1 a hello
2 b hi
3 c ahoi
```

Id like to delete a b and c.

Comment: Use `ps` and customize the output with `--format`

Comment: That's viable as well, thanks

Comment: In fact, cutting down a top output instead of using ps seems to be kind of stupid now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `cut` command.

```
 cut -d' ' -f2 --complement file
```

`--complement` does the inverse. i.e. with `-f2` second field was choosen. And with `--complement` if prints all fields except the second. This is useful when you have variable number of fields.

GNU's cut has the option `--complement`. In case, `--complement` is not available then, the following does the same:

cut -d' ' -f1,3- file

Meaning: print first field and then print from 3rd to the end i.e. Excludes second field and prints the rest.
**Edit:**

If you prefer `awk` you can do: `awk {$2=""; print $0}' file`

This sets the second to empty and prints the whole line (one-by-one).

Comment: `awk '{$2=""; print}' file` leaves an extra space however.

Comment: @sudo_O that's right. I guess as long as the fields are separated by whitespace, this is ok for whatever purpose the fields are used for.

Comment: Yes, just something to note.

Comment: I've never heard of --complement, is that a GNU thing? With regular cut you can just do `cut -d' ' -f1,3-`.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, `--complement` is in GNU/Linux. Not sure if there's an equivalent option in other OSes. Anyway, I updated my answer with this. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 5):

Using `sed` to substitute the second column:

```
sed -r 's/(\w+\s+)\w+\s+(.*)/\1\2/' file 
1 hello
2 hi
3 ahoi
```

Explanation:

```
(\w+\s+) # Capture the first word and trailing whitespace
\w+\s+   # Match the second word and trailing whitespace
(.*)     # Capture everything else on the line

\1\2     # Replace with the captured groups
```

Notes: Use the `-i` option to save the results back to the `file`, `-r` is for extended regular expressions, check the `man` as it could be `-E` depending on implementation.

Or use `awk` to only print the specified columns:

```
$ awk '{print $1, $3}' file
1 hello
2 hi
3 ahoi
```

Both solutions have there merits, the `awk` solution is nice for a small fixed number of columns but you need to use a temp file to store the changes `awk '{print $1, $3}' file > tmp; mv tmp file` where as the `sed` solution is more flexible as columns aren't an issue and the `-i` option does the edit in place.

Comment: Great explanation, awk seems to be the easier one to use.

Comment: I initially thought of awk. But with variable num of fields, a loop may be needed using `NF`. Already +1'd :)

Comment: @KingsIndian I have added some extra info on the merits of both.

Comment: the `-i` option to `sed` does create a temporary file. It's not directly visible to the user, though.

Comment: With GNU awk you can use gensub() the same way as the sed command above works.

Answer (score 3):

One way using `sed`:

```
sed 's/ [^ ]*//' file
```

Results:

```
1 hello
2 hi
3 ahoi
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Bash:

```
$ while read f1 f2 f3
> do
>  echo $f1 $f3
> done < file
1 hello
2 hi
3 ahoi
```

Comment: Fingers crossed your file doesn't contain +, ?, * or any other shell globbing characters or if it does you don't have any files in your directory that match the pattern. Always quote your variables unless you have a good reason not too. Fingers crossed also that your file doesn't contain any backslashes. Always write your loops as `while IFS= read -r line` unless you have a good reason not too. Finally - writing shell loops is rarely the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\S+\s+//2' file
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me that you can specify which occurence in `sed`